# How to make verbose mode always active?

Tags: php, composer-php

composer is usually very slow, and it provide no usual element to represent its progress. I always have to use `-vvv` option. Is there any way to make it always in verbose mode?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily on Linux with an alias.

```
alias composer="composer -vvv"
```

You can make this permanent by appending this line to your `.bash_profile` or equivalent in your home directory.

If you are running on Windows, you can create a batch file wrapper in your `PATH`, something like:

```
@echo off
composer -vvv %*
```

Both of these assume that Composer is in your `PATH` already - if this is not the case, you'll need to prefix it with the full path.